# Como pre visualizar un documento pdf en wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, pdf

Estuve buscando y no encontré nada o no supe como buscarlo, lo que tengo en mente es que quiero visualizar en una ventana emergenteo o pop up un archivo de PDF para que pueda ser leído sin la necesidad de que abra una nueva pestaña en el navegador.

Comment: probaste un iframe?

Comment: Me podrías explicar que eso? soy nuevo con estos temas y estoy aprendiendo independientemente. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este plugin:
[PDF-embedder](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/pdf-embedder/)

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero no es lo que necesito, y sigo sin encontrar la forma. Lo que quiero es que se visualice encima de la pantalla principal como una ventana emergente de fondo oscuro

Comment: En ese caso usted no necesita más que añadir el PDF a la biblioteca de medios.
Hecho esto, usted coge la URL del PDF que ha agregado a la biblioteca de medios.
Después, debe incluir un enlace en la página donde quiera insertarlo y allí escribir la URL que ha cogido y puede elegir si se abre en la misma ventana o en otra nueva.

(Parecía más difícil de lo que en realidad era, entonces)